# Trim a nsstring from an array? Not just whitespaces

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array with these elements

```
    deviceType = iOS,
    email = "test@test.se",
    lastname = Testsson,
    name = Testar,
    password = 1943B8B39CA8DF2919FAFF021E0ACA98,
    picture = <74657374 40746573 742e7365>,
    timeCreated = "2012-07-17 13:32:36 +0000",
    timeUpdated = "1999-11-30 00:00:00 +0000",
    userID = 13,
```

I want to remove everything before the equal sign and store it in a new array. Are there a fast and good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
NSMutableArray * keys = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString * element in yourAarray) {
    NSArray * components = [element componentsSeparatedByString: @" = "];
    [keys addObject: components[0]]
}
```